# MYSQL Definer Issue

Tags: mysql, mariadb, rds

There is a very strange issue. I have one procedure with a definer named as admin.

There was a case where we had to remove the user "dbadlys". So in order to do so we updated the mysql.proc table with the new account "admin@%" before deletion of account dbadlys and did the flush privileges as well.

I also verified the definer name from information_schema.routines and I saw that new definer name is now admin@%.

**Issue:**

Even though the definer name was now updated to new name when the code was calling the procedure it was using the old definer name dbadlys and was giving the below error:

> The user specified as a definer does not exist

Upon further investigation, I found out that when we reconnect the instance then there was no error, however if we change the definer name and try to execute the procedure again then it doesn't reflect it.

My questions:

1. Is there anything else which I need to do in this situation or am missing anything?
2. if there is nothing missing then is there a way that application should see the changes?
3. Should I restart the application server?

Answer (score 0):

If you have dba privilege, try recreating the SP without definer.

Definers are optional, unless you have a very specific need you don't need to use them.

Comment: Actually I am not quite sure about the dependency if definer is required by the SP.. However I want to ask why new definer is not being used by the SP when it is already been changed in the mysql.proc table. Please let me know about that.

Comment: mysql.proc is managed by MySQL , when you change the SP definition it updates the mysql.proc... don't think it works the reverse.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... however when the new connections were made then SP is getting called with the new definer name. This is something strange. Why after changing in mysql.proc is working for only new sessions and not from existing ones?

Comment: I think I got my ans:-  The server manipulates the mysql.proc table in response to statements that create, alter, or drop stored routines. It is not supported that the server will notice manual manipulation of this table.  from official documentation :- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-routines-privileges.html